# How to run a custom Slider

Tags: drake

I'm working on a simulation of a Soft Robot using the Piecewise Constant Curvature (PCC) assumption and representing each PCC segment with an Augmented Rigid Body Model (ARBM). For this I first would like to implement a manual slider for curvature control, i.e., a slider where I can input the two curvature parameters (Theta and Phi) and after mapping it to the ARBM via some known map `m(Theta, Phi)` showcase the robot in meshcat.

I'm already displaying the ARBM, however, am struggling to get the slider to run. As a result, I'd like to have something similar to the [Let's get you a Robot](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/Ch2-Lets-get-you-a-robot-8f86172b-b597-4ceb-9bad-92d11ac7a6cc/%2Frobot.ipynb) notebook from the Manipulation course. So ideally a kinematic simulation in which I can set the curvatures to show the resulting ARBM configuration.

As of right now, my approach is the following:

- Create a Custom Slider Class that is based on LeafSystem that creates two slides
- Create a Transformation System based on a VectorSystem that applies the map `m(Theta, Phi)` to the output of the sliders yielding the ARBM joint states on its output
- Set the Robot Joints to this State (**This is where I'm struggling**)

The problem seems to be that I cannot connect the desired output directly to the Joint positions in the same way that, e.g., the Joint sliders are. Is there a way to do this or should I follow a different approach?

See below for the code of the individual instances:

CurvatureSlider.py:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np

from pydrake.systems.framework import LeafSystem


class CurvatureSliders(LeafSystem):
    @dataclass
    class SliderDefault:
        """Default values for the meshcat sliders."""
        name: str
        """The name that is used to add / query values from."""
        default: float
        """The initial value of the slider."""

    _THETA = SliderDefault("Theta", 0.0)
    _PHI = SliderDefault("Phi", 0.0)

    def __init__(self, meshcat):
        """
        @param meshcat The already created pydrake.geometry.Meshcat instance.
        """

        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("theta_phi", 2, self.DoCalcOutput)
        self.meshcat = meshcat

        # Curvature Control Sliders
        self.meshcat.AddSlider(
            name=self._THETA.name, min=-2.0 * np.pi,
            max=2.0 * np.pi, step=0.01,
            value=self._THETA.default)
        self.meshcat.AddSlider(
            name=self._PHI.name, min=-2.0 * np.pi,
            max=2.0 * np.pi, step=0.01,
            value=self._PHI.default)

    def SetConfiguration(self, config: tuple):
        """
        @param pose Tuple of floats that is ordered (Theta, Phi)
        """
        assert(len(config) == 2)
        self.meshcat.SetSliderValue(self._THETA.name, config[0])
        self.meshcat.SetSliderValue(self._PHI.name, config[1])

    def DoCalcOutput(self, context, output):
        theta = self.meshcat.GetSliderValue(self._THETA.name)
        phi = self.meshcat.GetSliderValue(self._PHI.name)
        output.SetAtIndex(0, theta)
        output.SetAtIndex(1, phi)
```

CC2ARBM.py:

```
import numpy as np

from pydrake.systems.framework import VectorSystem


class CC2ARBM(VectorSystem):

    def __init__(self, L: float):
        """
        @param L The length of the segment.
        """
        VectorSystem.__init__(self, 2, 10)

        # Define length of the segment
        self._L = L

    def DoCalcVectorOutput(self, context, u, x, y):
        # Extract Input
        theta = u[0]
        phi = u[1]

        # Compute ARBM equivalent configuration
        b = 0.5 * self._L
        eta = 0
        if not theta == 0:
            b = self._L / theta * np.sqrt(1
                                          + 4 * np.sin(0.5 * theta) / theta
                                          * (np.sin(0.5 * theta) / theta)
                                          - np.cos(0.5 * theta))
            eta = np.arccos(1 / b * self._L / theta * np.sin(0.5 * theta))

        print("Computed ARBM Joint Position")
        # Aggreate Output
        y.SetAtIndex(0, phi)
        y.SetAtIndex(1, 0.5 * theta - eta)
        y.SetAtIndex(2, b)
        y.SetAtIndex(3, eta)
        y.SetAtIndex(4, - phi)
        y.SetAtIndex(5, phi)
        y.SetAtIndex(6, eta)
        y.SetAtIndex(7, b)
        y.SetAtIndex(8, 0.5 * theta - eta)
        y.SetAtIndex(9, - phi)
```

Main.py:

```
import sys
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from CurvatureSliders import CurvatureSliders
from CC2ARBM import CC2ARBM

from pydrake.geometry import (
    MeshcatVisualizerCpp,
    MeshcatVisualizerParams,
    Role,
    StartMeshcat
)

from pydrake.math import (
    RigidTransform,
    RotationMatrix
)

from pydrake.multibody.meshcat import JointSliders
from pydrake.multibody.tree import FixedOffsetFrame
from pydrake.multibody.parsing import Parser
from pydrake.multibody.plant import AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph

from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder
from pydrake.systems.primitives import LogVectorOutput


def do_main(teleop: bool,
            target_realtime_rate: float,
            simulation_time: float,
            max_time_step: float,
            description_path: str) -> None:

    # Start the visualizer.
    # The cell will output an HTTP link after the execution.
    # Click the link and a MeshCat tab should appear in your browser.
    meshcat = StartMeshcat()

    # Reset Meshcat Simulator
    meshcat.Delete()
    meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()

    # Init the Diagram Builder
    builder = DiagramBuilder()

    # Note: the time_step here is chosen arbitrarily.
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(
        builder, time_step=max_time_step)

    # Load the files into the plant/scene_graph.
    parser = Parser(plant)
    # L - Mount
    mount = parser.AddModelFromFile("../mount.sdf")
    # Robot
    model = parser.AddModelFromFile(description_path)

    # Create an offset frame located half the link height above the origin
    base_frame = plant.GetFrameByName("mount_base")
    offset_frame = plant.AddFrame(
        frame=FixedOffsetFrame(
            name="offset_frame",
            P=plant.world_frame(),
            X_PF=RigidTransform(
                R=RotationMatrix.Identity(),
                p=np.array([0, 0, 0.5])
            ),
            model_instance=None)
    )
    # Weld the base link to the offset frame
    plant.WeldFrames(offset_frame, base_frame)

    # Weld the robot base to the L-Mount
    robot_base_frame = plant.GetFrameByName("robot_base")
    robot_mounting_frame = plant.GetFrameByName("robot_location")
    plant.WeldFrames(robot_mounting_frame, robot_base_frame)

    # Finalize Plant
    plant.Finalize()

    #############################################################
    #              Post Plant Finalization Code                 #
    #############################################################

    # Set the Default states of the Joints
    for i in plant.GetJointIndices(model):
        j = plant.get_joint(i)
        if j.num_positions() == 1:
            j.set_default_positions([-0.2])

    # Make the control inputs of the model an input to the diagram.
    builder.ExportInput(plant.get_actuation_input_port())

    # Add two visualizers, one to publish the "visual" geometry, and one to
    # publish the "collision" geometry.
    visual = MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder(
        builder, scene_graph, meshcat,
        MeshcatVisualizerParams(
            role=Role.kPerception, prefix="visual")
    )
    collision = MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder(
        builder, scene_graph, meshcat,
        MeshcatVisualizerParams(role=Role.kProximity, prefix="collision"))
    # Disable the collision geometry at the start; it can be enabled by the
    # checkbox in the meshcat controls.
    meshcat.SetProperty("collision", "visible", False)

    # Setup Loggers
    plant_logger = LogVectorOutput(plant.get_state_output_port(), builder)

   
    # Joint Sliders Work like this
    # sliders = builder.AddSystem(JointSliders(meshcat, plant))

    # Add Curvature Sliders
    curv_sliders = builder.AddSystem(CurvatureSliders(meshcat))
    cc2arbm = builder.AddSystem(CC2ARBM(0.2))

    # Connect the Sliders to the transformation block
    builder.Connect(curv_sliders.get_output_port(0),
                    cc2arbm.get_input_port(0))

    # Build the diagram
    diagram = builder.Build()

    # Start runnin the teleoperation
    # Start Running the Slider similar to the Joint slider 
    # e.g. sliders.Run(diagram)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        do_main(target_realtime_rate=1,
                simulation_time=10.0,
                max_time_step=1.0e-3,
                description_path="single_cc_segment.sdf")
    else:
        do_main(target_realtime_rate=float(sys.argv[1]),
                simulation_time=float(sys.argv[2]),
                max_time_step=float(sys.argv[3]),
                description_path=sys.argv[4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few moving parts here.  First, you say "kinematic simulation", but the demonstration in "Let's get you a robot" does not simulate (physics), it only visualizes the kinematics as set by the sliders.  Assuming that is sufficient for your goal, then you could pass a callback into your `sliders.Run` method (as I do in the notebook corresponding to [this chapter](https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/pick.html)), and I believe that if you call `plant.SetPositions` in that callback, it should work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I did solve it using the plant.SetPosition but mostly tried to reimplement the JointSliders.Run(...) function.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually ran the custom slider using a reimplementation of JointSlider.Run(...). For me, the following was sufficient (Two planar constant curvature segments, represented by 4 rigid joints each):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np
import functools
import operator
import logging
import time
from typing import List, Tuple
from pydrake.systems.framework import LeafSystem


class CurvatureSliders(LeafSystem):
    @dataclass
    class SliderDefault:
        """Default values for the meshcat sliders."""
        name: str
        """The name that is used to add / query values from."""
        default: float
        """The initial value of the slider."""

    _Q1 = SliderDefault("q1", 0.0)
    _Q2 = SliderDefault("q2", 0.0)

    def __init__(self, meshcat, plant, L=0.2):
        """
        @param meshcat The already created pydrake.geometry.Meshcat instance.
        @param plant The plant the sliders are connected to
        @param L the restlength of the segment
        """

        # Call Super Constructor
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)

        # Declare System Output
        output = self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "q1_q2", 2, self.DoCalcOutput)
        output.disable_caching_by_default()

        # Init Class Variables
        self._meshcat = meshcat
        self._plant = plant
        self._L = L

        # Curvature Control Sliders
        self._meshcat.AddSlider(
            name=self._Q1.name, min=-2.0 * np.pi,
            max=2.0 * np.pi, step=0.1,
            value=self._Q1.default)
        self._meshcat.AddSlider(
            name=self._Q2.name, min=-2.0 * np.pi,
            max=2.0 * np.pi, step=0.1,
            value=self._Q2.default)

    def SetConfiguration(self, q: Tuple):
        """
        @param q configuration for each CC segment descriped by (q1, q2)
        """
        self._meshcat.SetSliderValue(self._Q1.name, q[0])
        self._meshcat.SetSliderValue(self._Q2.name, q[1])

    def CC2AGRB(self, q: Tuple) -> List[float]:

        # Extract input
        q1 = q[0]
        q2 = q[1]
        # Compute ARBM equivalent configuration
        config1 = [0, 0.5 * self._L, 0.5 * self._L, 0]
        config2 = [0, 0.5 * self._L, 0.5 * self._L, 0]

        if q1 != 0:
            config1 = [
                0.5 * q1,
                self._L * np.sin(0.5 * q1) / q1,
                self._L * np.sin(0.5 * q1) / q1,
                0.5 * q1
            ]
        if q2 != 0:
            config2 = [
                0.5 * q2,
                self._L * np.sin(0.5 * q2) / q2,
                self._L * np.sin(0.5 * q2) / q2,
                0.5 * q2
            ]

        return functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, [config1, config2], [])

    def DoCalcOutput(self, context, output):
        q1 = self._meshcat.GetSliderValue(self._Q1.name)
        q2 = self._meshcat.GetSliderValue(self._Q2.name)

        output.SetAtIndex(0, q1)
        output.SetAtIndex(1, q2)

    def Run(self, diagram, timeout=1e5):

        # Get all the contextes
        root_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
        sliders_context = self.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)
        plant_context = self._plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(root_context)

        # Add Stop Button
        kButtonName = "Stop Curvature Sliders"
        logging.info("Press the '{}' button in Meshcat to continue.",
                     kButtonName)
        self._meshcat.AddButton(kButtonName)

        # Greb current time to implement the timeout
        t0 = time.time()

        # Loop until the button is clicked, or
        # the timeout (when given) is reached.
        diagram.Publish(root_context)
        while self._meshcat.GetButtonClicks(kButtonName) < 1:
            # Break out of loop if timeout elapsed
            elapsed_t = time.time() - t0
            if elapsed_t >= timeout:
                break

            # If the sliders have not changed, avoid invalidating the context.
            old_positions = self._plant.GetPositions(plant_context)
            new_positions = self.CC2AGRB(
                self.get_output_port().Eval(sliders_context))
            if (np.abs(new_positions - old_positions) < 0.001).all():
                time.sleep(0.01)
                continue

            # Publish the new positions.
            self._plant.SetPositions(plant_context, new_positions)
            diagram.Publish(root_context)
```

And then just add them using the builder and calling the Run() function.